# Excel ISERROR invoice

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have created all the formulas for all the other aspects but How do you make a formula that can automatically detect if it is over the limit that is in stock. And when it does it can automatically recommend how much should be taken out.
(hopefully this is a bit more clearer)

[image: what the layout looks like]

Comment: hi Bazamee. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sorry, i am new to this, will improve right way :)

Comment: ok done editing the question :)

Comment: Please ellaborate what we see in your screenshot. And what exactly should happen where? Your question is still unclear

Comment: well, in the columns named description it should contain a formula that can detect if the quantity added exceeds the total about in the stoke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if your Stock List table is in Columns F to I and your description is in Column C, the following formula will return the Description if the quantity is less than stock levels or the text "Max stock is " etc:

```
=IF(B5<=VLOOKUP(A5,F:I,4,FALSE),VLOOKUP(A5,F:I,2,FALSE), "Max Stock is " & VLOOKUP(A5,F:I,4,FALSE))
```

Comment: @BAZAMEEE no worries, glad to be of help, next time it would help if you add more detail in your question, as I was only able to provide a formula after reading your last comment, also showing the columns in your picture would have also helped, as I had to guess which columns you are actually using... :)